# A start job is running for Persistent storage

Tags: boot, systemd

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but I updated it to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Now, when I turned my computer on, and pressed <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, my screen showed:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hUJ6.png)
and my computer restart itself.
After restart,and I pressed <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> again,my screen become like that:[image]

I must wait a while to start my Ubuntu.

What happened? Isn`t normal ? How can I fix this? Thank You.

Comment: Does it work if you wait for 1min 38 seconds?

Comment: Yes,it`s working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I already fix it. I change my Ubuntu18.04.2 become Ubuntu16.04.6,because my computer old and it can`t run the Ubuntu18.04.2 correctly.